# Deploy a react and node app to a digital ocean or heroku server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, digital-ocean

Can anyone please help me to deloy this app,
https://github.com/shashank7200/razorpay-react-demo,
to a digital ocean or a heroku server.
I have tried a lot and the app runs perfectly on my localhost server but I am not sure what configurations are needed to deploy it on heroku.

I have deployed this on heroku and here is the link:
https://secure-wave-18557.herokuapp.com/

The issue here is that it doesn't display the frontend for the the app which is written in react.js

Thanks

Comment: You likely need to add a buildpack for NodeJS. Take a look at the javascript console and server log for error messages.

Comment: Thanks @Nuclearman I have added a buildpack which builds the build.js file. My browser console shows this error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'.  In the inspector section my react app shows and empty container like this: <div id="root"></div>, it is not loading the contents of my js file.